# SQL Group by - Listing all rows by group?

Tags: sql, mysql

Given data such as

```
Type    Value
A       This
A       is
B       Will
A       a
B       this
A       test
B       work
```

I would like to end up with

```
Type    Value
A       This is a test
B       Will this work
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT Type, GROUP_CONCAT(Value SEPARATOR ' ') AS Value
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Type;
```

Ensuring the words are concatenated in the order you want can be tricky, however.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` has an `ORDER BY` clause (see the docs) but your example doesn't include any column that can be used to determine the order.  Relying on the physical storage order isn't reliable.